# Is a Schauder Basis a minimal total set?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given that the span of Schauder Basis - $S\subset V$ is $V$ itself, this implies that it is a total set. My teacher said that it was minimal as well but did not go on to prove it. I suspect it might be true given the uniqueness of representations of vectors in the "span" of a Schauder basis but I can't seem to show it.

Comment: If $(s_n)$ is the basis, for fixed $m$, $s_m^*(x)=0$ whenever $x$ is an element of $U={\rm span}\{ s_i : i\ne m\}$. Then $s_m (x)=0$ for any $x$ in the closure of $U$ by continuity.

Comment: ... I meant to write "$s_m^*(x)$" in the last sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry what is $s*_m(x)$?

Comment: The coefficient functional for $s_m$. $s_m^*(\sum\alpha_i s_i) =\alpha_m$. We have $s_j^*(s_i)=0$ if $i\ne j$ and $s_j^*(s_j)=1$ for all $j$. One can show the coefficient functionals are continuous.

Comment: Im sorry but im kinda slow so ive got a couple of questions. To show that $S$ is a minimal total set we have to show that if $F$ is a total set it is not a subset of $S$. I dont see how the coefficient functional describes that. Secondly, whats the domain of the  function is it V?

Comment: I think i got it. Suppose $F\subset S$ s.t $V_m$ is not $\in F$. Therefore, we can consider the coefficient functional from V to R which maps all elements in F to zero. Since, the function is continuous, the preimage of $\{0\}$ is closed. Therefore all elements in closure of F are mapped to zero. Since F is dense this implies that $V_m$ is mapped to 0. Contradiction

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted. What I showed is that if $(s_i)$ is a Schauder basis of $X$, then for every $n$, $s_n$ is not in the closed linear span of $\{ s_j : j\ne n\}$. (i.e., a basic sequence is *minimal*.)

Comment: I see but is the above proof sound? (F is a total set) and the coefficient functional is $S^*_{m}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89163/discussion-between-jhon-doe-and-david-mitra).